# Unexpected result with multiple commas in an array initializer

Tags: javascript

```
var a = [,,,];
var b = new Array(3);
0 in a     //  true??
0 in b     //  false
```

---

When I try this code in a browser, the result isn't what I expect. The result of `0 in a` is `false`.

I think `a = [,,,]` is not same as `a = [undefined,undefined,undefined]`,
it's same as `a = new Array(3)`. Am I right? What is the correct result of this?

Comment: What are all the downvotes for? Elisions are relatively new and easily misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the correct result of this?

The correct result is that `0 in a` is `false`, because `a` doesn't have an entry for the key `"0"`, because `a` doesn't have any entries at all. `a`'s `length` is 3, but it has no entries in it.

> I think `a = [,,,]` is not same as `a = [undefined,undefined,undefined]`

Correct, it is not.

> ...it's same as `a = new Array(3)`

Correct.

This is determined by [the runtime semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of an array initializer. When you have an *elision* in an array initializer, it does not create an entry in the array, but it *does* contribute to the length of the array. The array is a "sparse" array (an array with gaps).

Let's break it down:

```
var a = [
    /* blank space where entry 0 would be */,
    /* blank space where entry 1 would be */,
    /* blank space where entry 2 would be */,
    /* this isn't a blank space, a single trailing comma is ignored */
];
```

The first thing to note is that the `,` at the **end** is ignored, because a single trailing comma in an array initializer is always ignored. That leaves us with an array with three blank spaces in it, hence a length of `3`.

Here's an example without the potentially-confusing final `,`:

```js
var a = [1,,,4];
console.log(0 in a);   // true, `a` has an entry at 0
console.log(1 in a);   // false, `a` has no entry at 1
console.log(2 in a);   // false, `a` has no entry at 2
console.log(3 in a);   // true, `a` has an entry at 3
console.log(a.length); // 4
```

The blank spaces between `,` are exactly that: Blank spaces. They are not the same as `undefined`.

Comment: oh,got it ! maybe the code in book is  out of date. in my daily coding ,I should find the result in coding ,but not in outdated books.

Comment: @yangyang: Well, it depends, not all JavaScript engines are fully compliant with the specification; it's worth checking the spec to be sure. Separately: If that code block is from a book you have, you should say that in the question (including what book -- and what edition -- it is), e.g. "I have this in [book name here] [edition] edition:".

Comment: thanks for your remind.this code block is in 《JavaScript权威指南(第6版)》[JavaScript: The Definitive Guide(sixth)].  it's found at page 147.(section 7.3). what I say above，just means I should try more.

Comment: @yangyang: I just used Amazon's "Look Inside" to look inside JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition. Nothing on page 147 has `a = [,,,]` (nor pages around there, except the preview doesn't show page 148 so I can't be absolutely certain of page 148). Nor would it: It was published in 2011, **long** before array elisions were valid.